# SQL Rookie is having trouble getting one SQL statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this and has roughly 6000 rows (records) and table is called ItemRecords

```
ItemID | Colour | Size | Delivered
```

ItemID is the primary key

Delivered can only have two values.  Yes or No.

I am having trouble getting one SQL statement that chooses the next row where it is "No"

Is it

```
SELECT * FROM ItemRecords WHERE Delivered = "No"
```

The above gives me all the rows where Delivered = "No" but I only want the first found row where Delivered = "No"

Or is it normal to get all the rows and then only work with the first row of the entire result returned?

Comment: Add a `LIMIT 1` at the end?

Comment: remember that there is no real order to data in a sql database...without defining what row is 'first' (via date field or itemID sequence?).  Otherwise you might get a different top row every time you run it.

Comment: Do you have a good reason to "work with" one row rather than all relevant rows at once?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `LIMIT 1` to the end of your query.

`SELECT * FROM ItemRecords WHERE Delivered = "No" LIMIT 1`

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is pretty much meaningless.

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for your awesome advice, Strawberry!  Then should it be

   `SELECT * FROM ItemRecords WHERE Delivered = "No" LIMIT 1 ORDER BY ItemID`  ?

Comment: @Strawberry Then what is the SQL statement you would give in this situation?